# Get the max number of concurrent Windows RDS/TSE connetions

Tags: c++, windows

I'm currently creating a software written in C/C++ in in which I would need to know the max number of concurrent RDS/TSE connexions allowed on the host machine.

Until now I haven't been able to find a way to retrieve this information in bare C/C++.

I found that `Mstlsapi.dll` can only be found if RDS is installed, I was hoping there would be a function in it which would allow me to get this information but i haven't found anything yet.

Since this information will be retrieve at software startup I would like to avoid using "high cost" alternative solution as much as possible. (for example : querying a report to TSE service and parsing it through a powershell script)

Any help will be appreciated, thanks by advance.